# Heroku WIill Not Run Geckodriver in Docker (No Display, gecko port in use)

Tags: python, docker, selenium, heroku, geckodriver

Im trying to use Heroku to run a Docker container ( dockerfile for reference: https://pastebin.com/daNNWydP ). While I am using Heroku, I will deploy to other platforms so I am trying to get one Dockerfile to serve all my content instead of using something like Heroku buildpacks
The dockerfile is supposed to install all libraries, then run setup_env.py ( https://pastebin.com/66NCZ3yM ) which is responsible for installing Firefox & Geckodriver on the Docker container.

Finally, we get to the two important files:

The server.py (runs the server)  https://pastebin.com/hTJY0NiJ

The TestClass.py (Class object that runs selenium) https://pastebin.com/1mDt554S

However, I can never get it to work! The server replies this:

```
{
  "error": "Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 11\n", 
  "firefox_ver": "Command '['firefox', '-V']' returned non-zero exit status 1.", 
  "geckodriver_ver": "Command '['geckodriver', '-V']' returned non-zero exit status 69.", 
  "msg": "There was an error while trying to run Selenium", 
  "osbitver": "64bit", 
  "status": 0
}
```

and the Heroku logs says this:

```
2020-11-11T05:23:09.316540+00:00 app[web.1]:    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.

2020-11-11T05:23:09.316607+00:00 app[web.1]:    Use a production WSGI server instead.

2020-11-11T05:23:09.316663+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debug mode: on

2020-11-11T05:23:09.330774+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:13290/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

2020-11-11T05:23:09.331782+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Restarting with stat

2020-11-11T05:23:10.008689+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debugger is active!

2020-11-11T05:23:10.009991+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debugger PIN: 273-956-448

2020-11-11T05:23:10.259485+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up

2020-11-11T05:23:32.065373+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=testdemosite-onl-us-hru.herokuapp.com dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=158 protocol=https

2020-11-11T05:23:32.057560+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.236.68 - - [11/Nov/2020 05:23:32] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -

2020-11-11T05:23:33.343589+00:00 app[web.1]: geckodriver: error: Address in use (os error 98)

2020-11-11T05:23:33.422608+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified

2020-11-11T05:23:39.050568+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.236.68 - - [11/Nov/2020 05:23:39] "[37mGET /selenium HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -

2020-11-11T05:23:39.054198+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/selenium" host=testdemosite-onl-us-hru.herokuapp.com dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5725ms status=200 bytes=491 protocol=https
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is Firefox not being recognized even though theres a symlink in /bin? Why is geckodriver saying the port is being used? Whats this display error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are Heroku Docker Registry I suggest a different solution: create a single container running the application and Firefox.
The application can use the Selenium Gecko driver to connect to Firefox local process as you can do on your local dev environment (or on other platforms).

Here is an example of Dockerfile (note I use chrome but a similar setup is possible with Firefox)

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

# install tools
RUN apt -f install
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && apt-get install -y wget && apt-get install bzip2 -y && apt-get install unzip -y

# Install geckodriver
#RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.27.0/geckodriver-v0.27.0-linux64.tar.gz && \
#    tar -zxf geckodriver-v0.27.0-linux64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin && \
#    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/geckodriver && \
#    rm geckodriver-v0.27.0-linux64.tar.gz

# Install chromeDriver
RUN wget -q "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.88/chromedriver_linux64.zip" \
-O /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
&& unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /usr/local/bin/ \
&& rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip

# install chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

# copy Python files
COPY app/ /app

EXPOSE 5000

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Example (run Flask app with Waitress using Heroku $PORT)
CMD waitress-serve  --host='0.0.0.0' --port=$PORT --call 'app:create_app'
```

The Python code is pretty straight-forward since Firefox is running as local process

```
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```